# set string to a certain position

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, padding

I am trying to email a checklist but I can't get the rows to line up.

```
string aheading = "Defects:";
string bheading = "Comments:";

string result = aheading.PadRight(20, ' ') + bheading.PadRight(20, ' ') + Environment.NewLine;

foreach (var item in chkList.CheckItems)
{
    if (item.Defect == true)
    {
        result += item.ItemTitle.Trim().PadRight(20,' ') +  item.Comment.Trim().PadRight(20,' ') + Environment.NewLine ; 
    }
}
```

In the database there is a list of defects and comments, so the code loops around to display each defect and it's comment on separate lines but it looks like this:

```
Defects:            Comments:                     
Vehicle Secure           comment1                      
Brakes              comment2
```

Is there a way to get the comments to line up? It's like the `vehicle secure` string is pushing the comment out. There could be a long list of defects and I won't know how long each string will be so can I set the comments to display in a certain position?

Comment: Get the length of `item.ItemTitle` and use it to have the second column align the way you want.

Comment: You need to use a fixed width font (Courier?) as different characters will take up a different amount of space, and things won't line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count the length of string.

First, go through all your `CheckItems` and find the longest `ItemTitle`

Second, make a variable `padding` to put the max padding.

Finally, you can count each line's padding by using [String.Format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/)

```
string aheading = "Defects:";
string bheading = "Comments:";

int maxlength = 0;
foreach (var item in chkList.CheckItems)
{
    if (item.ItemTitle.Length > maxlength)
        maxlength = item.ItemTitle.Length;
}

int padding = maxlength + 10;  //10 spaces between the longest 'Defects' and its 'Comments'
string format = "{0,-" + padding + "} {1,-" + padding + "}\r\n"

string result = String.Format(format, "Defects:", "Comments:");

foreach (var item in chkList.CheckItems)
{
    if (item.Defect == true)
    {
        result += String.Format(format, item.ItemTitle, Item.Comment);
    }
}
```

**Note**

Each of the characters in your current font should have the same width.

You should use [Monospaced Font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) in your mail to make this work properly.

If you wish it to work on every font. See @Gelootn's answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Format your string as HTML, then you could use tables to format. the mailmessage has a property to set its content as Html.

```
            var htmlstring = "<table>";
            htmlstring += "<tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>";
            foreach (var row in content)
            {
                htmlstring += string.Format("<tr><td>text</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", row.data);
            }

            htmlstring += "</table>";

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = htmlString;
```

implementing the code from the question

```
        string aheading = "Defects:";
        string bheading = "Comments:";

        string result = string.Format("<table><tr><th>{0}</th><th>{1}</th></tr>", aheading, bheading);

        foreach (var item in chkList.CheckItems)
        {
            if (item.Defect == true)
            {
                result += string.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", item.ItemTitle.Trim(), item.Comment.Trim());
            }
        }

        result += "</table>";

        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = result;

        // SEND MESSAGE
        var client = new SmtpClient("mailhost");
        // If auth is needed
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        client.Send(message);
```

Comment: Using tables is a easy and simple way to format the mail, regardless font width problems. +1 for the inspiration.

Comment: thanks for the example but I'm not sure how I would apply this to my code

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Format, rather than .padright.

Create a string such as:

```
string title = String.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10}\n", "Defects:", "Comments:");
```

Then in your loop use:

```
string result = String.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10}\n", item.ItemTitle, item.Comment);
```

You will have to adjust the values to get it to look how you are happy with.